# TreeView adding and sorting

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode, revit-api, revit

I have treeView sorted in my Autodesk Revit and I would like to show it same way in my windows form.
At this time I was able to extract it just the way it looks in Revit (print log), but i cant figure out how to add it.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
            FilteredElementCollector schedules = new FilteredElementCollector(currDocument).
            OfClass(typeof(ViewSchedule));
        foreach (ViewSchedule schedule in schedules) {
            List<FolderItemInfo> folderfields = org.GetFolderItems(schedule.Id).ToList();
            foreach (FolderItemInfo s in folderfields) {
                print.Add(s.Name);
            }
            print.Add(schedule.Name);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzqBa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [BrowserOrganisation class](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/4fd57c3f-6127-efd9-f79e-70ad3e5dc1cc.htm) will help.

Maybe its [GetFolderItems method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/6d61981d-4d9c-477c-a85a-6ae375bc8cfc.htm) returns the folder items that you are listing in the same order as they are displayed in the Revit panel.

Comment: yes thank you, GetFolderItems has given me the same order as in Revit but I'm looking for a command to add Nodes to the treeView in the same order.
for example: GetFolderitems will return a letter with index as in the attached image.
how do I gradually add them?
Like this: 
treeView.Nodes.Add(folderfields[0].Name);
for (int k = 1; k < folderFieldCount ; k++)
{
  treeView.Nodes[k - 1].Nodes.Add(folderfields[k].Name);
}

Comment: How about [searching for `.net add sorted treeview nodes`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=.net+add+sorted+treeview+nodes)?